# Comparing image alts using jQuery

Tags: jquery, compare, alt

i am making a little project with simple hmtl and jquery, and i'm expecting difficult right at the moment with that issue : over the html i have simple images like this:

```
<img src="color.png" alt="color" width="44" height="46" /> 
<img src="gray.png" alt="gray" width="44" height="46" />
```

but sometimes the alts are identical, so i want to make a "check function" in jquery that compares and checks the alts of the images and if they are equal to execute an alert. I come to here but it don't work

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var grayBall = $("img[alt*='gray']");
        var colorBall = $("img[alt*='color']");

        if(colorBall.attr('alt') = grayBall.attr('alt')){
        alert("They are matching !");
        };  
    });
```

everything like adding the jquery to the html is ok only this function don't work.

Comment: to compare use `==` double equals - also they don't equal eachother so why would it alert?  can you explain some more as to what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `==` (equality) instead of `=` (assignment)

```
if(colorBall.attr('alt') == grayBall.attr('alt'))
{
    alert("They are matching !");
};
```

**Update** Have you tried this? Change the alt tag of one img and also change the selector in your script:

```
<img src="color.png" alt="color" width="44" height="46" /> 
<img src="gray.png" alt="color" width="44" height="46" />


jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var grayBall = $("img[alt*='color']");
    var colorBall = $("img[alt*='color']");

    if(colorBall.attr('alt') == grayBall.attr('alt')) {
        alert("They are matching !");
    };  
});
```

Comment: @Daemonyoyo, your `images` have different `alt` so it won't alert.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what doesn't work? Are you seeing any errors? What happens when you step through the code?

Comment: @SheikhHeera is right. Your selectors are based on the alt attribute, they will never be the same.

Comment: yes i understand this so i on purpose have changed the alts to be the same, but the problem is still there.I understand that you know more on jquery than me, but i am trying what you say and it doesn't work. The only time it worked is when i changed the code to " if(colorBall.attr('alt') = 'gray') " .

Comment: Thanks,it help in a slightly different way by showing me that my logic is not correct. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

**HTML**

```
<img src="gray.png" alt="gray" width="44" height="46" />
<img src="color.png" alt="color" width="44" height="46" />
<img src="gray.png" alt="gray" width="44" height="46" />
<img src="gray.png" width="44" height="46" />
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var exists = {};
    $("img[alt]").each(function(){
        var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
        if (exists[alt]) alert($(this).attr('alt')+" is matching !");
        else exists[alt] = true;
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/brBTe/).